# need to filter data based on no. of days for one record from column along with all the actual records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables. Caseclaims and  claimstates , from these tables i am getting the resultant  , claimcount and conditional counf for claimstates such as SENT, ACCEPTED , CLAIM STATUS REQUESTED .

NOW  , MY requirement is along with count for all claimstates , i need  to filter the count for 'SENT' BASED ON primaryADJUDICATIONDAYS (THIS IS FROM ANOTHER TABLE)

Comment: Formatting is disgusting. Improve your question. Add the structure of tables.

Comment: Please add details of your tables, sample data and expected results inline with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for.Add table structure by using  `DESC <table_name>` with your question which will greatly help contributors.

just ansering on assumptions: try `GROUP BY` statement on which want to count. i.e.:

```
SELECT COUNT(status) FROM ...... .... .... GROUP BY (on which column u want to count)
```